# RFduino device required for RFduino hex file

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, electronics, pcb-design

So I have been working trying to measure the velocity of a string attaches using Rfduino microcontroller.
I have downloaded all the library(based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0JiPQnrkHQ) and check the PCB all the connection via multimeter ( i have made the PCB, and assemble via Chineses manufacture). and connect PCB to my laptop via FTDI board as this;
[image]

When I compile the code it. It's compiled nicely. But when I try to download the code it says

```
RFduino device required for RFduino hex file
```

Does anyone had any experience with this sort of error message?
(this is my first question in this forum. I don't no this belong to hardware or software side)

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to program **RFD22302** micro using RFD22121 USB shield and USB MicroB Plug Breakout board.

[RFD22302](https://sg.rs-online.com/web/p/bluetooth-modules/8011698/)

[USB Development Kit-RFD22121](https://sg.rs-online.com/web/p/products/8011695/)

[USB MicroB Plug Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10031)

any help would be appreciated!
Thanks, Heaps!

Comment: https://crownstone.rocks/2014/03/05/rfduino-without-rfduino-code

Comment: Hi Juraj, unfortunately, the link page video doent work and im trying program RFD22302 micro!